# Proof of ∀ ∈  (( ∈ )↔($^2$ ∈ ))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

**Let  = {−2, −1,0,1,2},  = {0,1,4} and  = {−4, −3, −2, −1,0,1,2,3,4}.**

**Prove if ∀ ∈  (( ∈ )↔($^2$ ∈ )) is true/false.**

This is my attempt at the proof, I am not sure if it is correct. Is there a more concise way of proving without using proof by exhaustion?

Also, is there a better way to express lines 1.1 and 2.1?

Thank you!
[image: Edited]

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to do this by exhaustive proof. Normally what we would write is something like "Let $x\in C$ such that $x\in A$" and proceed to list each case. And similarly, for $\Leftarrow$, "Let $x\in C$ such that $x^2\in B$."

Comment: @travvytree Thank you, I have edited the proof, is this correct?

Comment: Yes it looks fine. :)

Comment: "...is this correct?"  Looks perfectly **valid** to me.

Comment: What are you using to write math statements that is making all the variables appear as the same rectzngle?